# Import source code folder from a existing program into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, project

I just wanted to edit a existing program (or project) where I have the source code folder (which has already java files, not class files... so I don't have to decompile that) of that. But how do I import that in Eclipse?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have a maven build file (`pom.xml`), then it's pretty easy: do a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the pom file. That will create a project at that location (iaw, it will create a `.project` and a `.classpath` file).

Then, simply import the project into a workspace.

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` has been deprecated for years, since the introduction of the Eclipse m2e project.

Answer (score 0):

With Neon: `File > Open projects from filesystem...`. With older versions or if you prefer it in Neon, `File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects`.